# Android Fragments opening on top of each other in tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

So I have a `FragmentPagerAdapter` that has 4 different tabs. Each one opens a fragment. The `getItem` method is established as follows:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:{
                return new FragmentOne();
            }
            case 1:{
                return new FragmentTwo();
            }
            case 2:{
                return new FragmentThree();
            }
            case 3:{
                return new FragmentFour();
            }
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

However, although no errors are thrown it does not display correctly. The first tab has `FragmentFour` and the other three remaining tabs are empty.

What could be causing this problem?

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the break steatement that you forgot or doing the work with this code :

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (i == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentOne();
    } else if (i == 1) {
        fragment = new FragmentTwo();
    } else if (i == 2) {
        fragment = new FragmentThree();
    } else if (i == 3) {
        fragment = new FragmentFour();
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

or by adding the break statements as follows:

```
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
Fragment fragment = null;
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new FragmentOne();
        break;
    case 1
        fragment =  new FragmentTwo();
    break;
    case 2:
        fragment =  new FragmentThree();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment =  new FragmentFour();
        break;
return fragment;
}
```

Good luck..

Comment: That's just conditionals replacing the case...switch

Comment: No my friend.. it replaces the switch statement and creates the Fragment only if the index is appropriate unlike the code of OP that create the Fragment in each 'case'!!

Comment: ...only because he forgot the `break` statements... otherwise his code is fine, and switch should be preferable imo

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. It seems to produce the same result.
In the fragments, could there be something?

Comment: add the break statement for each case.. i'm sure that it will solve your problem

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't fix it. Anyways this should be unnecessary as even the sample code the Android uses just has cases with return statements - no breaks.